How to disable drag and drop in Drawflow package in Angular?
I am using the drawflow package to create a workflow.
I want to disable drag-and-drop functionality from elements this demo as mentioned in the below image, not in the sidebar. In my demo, I want disable drag-and-drop functionality for all elements.

I already used the below option, but it's stopped my plus icon functionality, as seen in My demo.
this.editor.editor_mode = "fixed";

My demo

I also want this view in Vertical mode in the center.

there's an element attribute for that called "draggable": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable  By default most elements are set as draggable.
